# C# - Unity - audio when two objects collide, not working :(

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a problem. I am creating a small game project where where a ball escapes from ghosts.

I am trying to write a script that plays "evil laughter" when the ball collides with a ghost.

When i added the audio upon collision code into the script, the other function which gets the player to the "Game over"-scene stops working

Does anyone know what the problem might be?
Thanks a lot in advance! (code below) <3

```
public class GhostScript : MonoBehaviour

public AudioSource ghostCollision; //this is the collision sound reference

public GameObject target;   //this is the player or a reference for him
UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent agent;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    ghostCollision = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    agent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
    if (target == null) { 
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    agent.destination = target.transform.position;
}

public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player"){

        ghostCollision.Play();
        SceneManager.LoadScene("menu");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because as soon as you call `SceneManager.LoadScene` the current scene (which contains your Player, AI and AudioSource) gets lost and replaced with the new [Scene](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingScenes.html). Adding a delay to the scene load should do the trick, you can use [Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) for that (or [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) if you're more advanced).

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
   if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
   {
      ghostCollision.Play();

      // Invokes the function after the AudioClip is over
      Invoke("LoadScene", ghostCollision.clip.length);
   }
}

private void LoadScene()
{
   SceneManager.LoadScene("your-scene-name");
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! That should help!

Comment: Happy to be helpful.